# permutations of n objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Does the number of permutations of $n$ objects, $r$ alike of one kind and $n−r$ alike of another kind, always equal the combinations of n different objects taken $r$ at a time? Explain.

I know permutations are $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ and combinations are $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

the question is wordy so im not sure what it is asking but is it asking if

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$=$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ ? because the answer to that would be no

Comment: The answer is yes. The formula you use for permutations is wrong. The interpretation of the formula you use is the amount of permutations for $n$ objects, $n-r$ alike of one kind and the rest distinguishable and unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **yes**

See, you know that the permutation formula for $n$ distinct objects can be simplified to $n!$

But if there are, say $a$ of one kind and $b$ of another, with $a+b=n$, you know that the formula changes to $\frac{n!}{a!b!}$

In the present case, $a= r, b = n-r,$ so formula becomes $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, which is identical to the combination formula of choosing $r$ objects at a time from $n$ objects.

**Added:**

The formula $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ that you mention is the permutation formula of $r$ objects at a time being taken from $n$ objects, i.e. $^nP_r\;\; or\;\; P(n,r) = r!\binom{n}{r}$